# best way to replace a value in 2nd table where value in 1st table has updated?

Tags: mysql

im trying to find the last time a value was inputted into table 1 and then input that value into table 2
however due to the sheer size of table 1 (this gets truncated daily) it either takes forever or i end up losing connection to the server

I tried to use a after insert trigger but it would run i then created an event to run every couple hours but again after the 1st time it would run.

The query im currently using is

```
replace into database.table2 (value1,value2,date,time)
select value1,value2,date,time from database.table1;
```

value 1 is a unique value which is the reason for using replace as I only want 1 instance (string) of this value.

Example Data    Table1

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Value1 | Value2       | DATE          | TIME     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1      | red          | 01/08/2018    | 10:33:15 |
| 2      | red          | 01/08/2018    | 10:33:20 |
| 3      | red          | 01/08/2018    | 10:33:21 |
| 4      | red          | 01/08/2018    | 10:33:23 |
| 1      | red          | 01/08/2018    | 10:36:15 |
| 1      | red          | 01/08/2018    | 10:38:15 |
| 2      | red          | 01/08/2018    | 10:38:15 |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Example Data    Table2 Desired Outcome where the value pulled over from table1 is the latest value in the table

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Value1 | Value2       | DATE          | TIME     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1      | red          | 01/08/2018    | 10:38:15 |
| 2      | red          | 01/08/2018    | 10:38:15 |
| 3      | red          | 01/08/2018    | 10:33:21 |
| 4      | red          | 01/08/2018    | 10:33:23 |
----------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE table1 (

value1 int primary key,
value2 varchar(10),
Date date,
Time time
);

INSERT INTO table1 (value1,value2, Date, Time)
Values (1, 'red', '2018-08-01', '10:33:15' ),
(2, 'red', '2018-08-01', '10:33:20' );
(3, 'red', '2018-08-01', '10:33:21' );
(4, 'red', '2018-08-01', '10:33:23' );
(1, 'red', '2018-08-01', '10:36:15' );
(1, 'red', '2018-08-01', '10:18:15' );
(2, 'red', '2018-08-01', '10:38:15' );



CREATE TABLE table2 (

value1 varchar(10) primary key,
value2 varchar(10),
Date date,
Time time
);
```

Hopefully i have written those correctly as i normally use workbench to create tables

Comment: Can you show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` statement for every table involved in the question?

Comment: Besides your current query is pretty wrong you can't trust MySQL into selecting the records in the same order always without using ORDER BY.

Comment: will replace into not take the latest value in table 1? my issue was it was just taking up a lot of resources?

Comment: Talking about the `select value1,value2,date,time from database.table1;`

Comment: The query also would be more eazier when you use datetime datatype instead of using two columns

Comment: the date and time are kept seperate due to reporting in something else which needs those 2 columns seperate

Comment: @AvalonParkes-barton That sounds like an implausible excuse, but if true, have a separate column anyway that stores the date and time correctly, as a single entity. (Well done for almost providing DDLs, BTW)

Comment: you have lost me now haha im not sure what ddl's are ?
i mean the only reason for the seperate columns are due to sorting of datatables on an external webpage I guess i can join these together and still get the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer; too long for a comment.

Let's start with the only bit of this that presently makes any sense:

```
INSERT INTO Test (id,present,datetime) VALUES
(1, 'red', '2018-08-01 10:33:15' ),
(2, 'red', '2018-08-01 10:33:20' );
(3, 'red', '2018-08-01 10:33:21' );
(4, 'red', '2018-08-01 10:33:23' );
(1, 'red', '2018-08-01 10:36:15' );
(1, 'red', '2018-08-01 10:18:15' );
(2, 'red', '2018-08-01 10:38:15' );
```

This data set has no PRIMARY KEY. Before we go any further, it needs one.

Comment: is value1 not the primary key? sorry i added the wrong header on create table i have updated them

Comment: Let's stick with the headings above. The first requirement of a primary key is that it's unique. Clearly, id is not unique.

Comment: ah okay i get you now urm no then value1 is only unique in table 2

Answer (score 0):

To find most recent values you can do something like this

```
SELECT t1.value1, t1.value2, t1.date, t1.time
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table1 t2
  ON (t1.value1 = t2.value1 AND concat(t1.date,' ',t1.time) < concat(t2.date,' ',t2.time)) WHERE t2.date IS NULL;
```

AND then use that with your `Replace`

```
REPLACE INTO table2 (value1,value2,date,time)
SELECT t1.value1, t1.value2, t1.date, t1.time
    FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table1 t2
      ON (t1.value1 = t2.value1 AND concat(t1.date,' ',t1.time) < concat(t2.date,' ',t2.time)) WHERE t2.date IS NULL;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbbc27/1
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/2397717

Comment: so this works but im still getting the issue that its taking so long using replace that its losing connection from the server 4/5 attempts i mean in t1 i have over 400000 entry value's